# Implementation of a polymorphic [] operator for accessing a std::variant

Tags: c++, c++17, type-deduction, std-variant

Suppose I have a struct `MyMap`, which is a wrapper for `std::map` where value type is `std::variant<A, B>` but A and B behave completely different (they have different member functions and fields, and share no common functionality).

For example:

```
#include <map>
#include <variant>
#include <string>

struct A {
   std::string val;
};

struct B {
   int val;
};

struct MyMap {
   std::map<int, std::variant<A, B>> internalMap;
};
```

I want to implement an `operator[]` overload for `MyMap` such that the type of the accesed element is the actual type `A` or `B`.

To clarify further, i DO NOT want this:
`std::variant<A, B> operator[](int key) { return internalMap[key]; }`
, but I want something like:

```
// If I have:

MyMap m;
m.internalMap[1] = A{};
m.internalMap[2] = B{};

// I want the type of internalMap[1] to be A, and type of internalMap[2] to be B:
A a = m.internalMap[1];
B b = m.internalMap[2];
```

I want to be able to call methods specific to type `A` or type `B` after accessing them with this `operator[]` overload.

Should this type deduction happen at runtime or at compile time (and how)?

Comment: Unfortunately, C++ does not work this way. The return value of all functions must be specified at compile time. It cannot vary at runtime. This is fundamental to C++, and there are no workarounds or exceptions. About the only thing you can do is create a wrapper object with an operator overload that calls `std::get` on the underlying returned variant.

Comment: Maybe Unions could help you out

Comment: @MichiBros `std::variant` is already an union, but typesafe. There's nothing to gain from replacing `variant` with `union` here.

Comment: What if you write `B b = m.internalMap[1];`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
struct AorB : public std::variant<A, B> {
    using std::variant<A, B>::variant;

    operator A&() {return std::get<A>(*this);}
    operator const A&() const {return std::get<A>(*this);}
    operator B&() {return std::get<B>(*this);}
    operator const B&() const {return std::get<B>(*this);}
};
```

And then you store this as the value of the map. Then, you can pass this to methods expecting an `A` or a `B`, and it works, as long as it's unambiguous.

```
A a = m.internalMap[1]; //no problem!
B b = m.internalMap[2];
```

[Proof of execution](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8083b09ea0262398)

Comment: @TheMemeMachine I have fixed the syntactical issues. The C++ does indeed allow overloading functions that defer only in return type, but ONLY for type-conversion operators, which this is using.  The `using` statement has been fixed, that causes the class to inherit the constructors.

Comment: @TedLyngmo: At the time of his comment, the code didn't compile. I'd fixed the code after his comment.  Oh, you're hinting that he should check the green arrow to the left below the vote buttons to mark that this was the answer? Yes, that would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

> I want the type of internalMap[1] to be A, and type of internalMap[2] to be B

That's impossible. What type the expression `m.internalMap[i]` has is complete determined by the types and value categories of `m` and `i` and the mapping is determined completely at compile-time. C++ is a statically-typed language. (There is one exception though: Integer literals with value `0` have additional conversion rules, so they can result in different types of the expression.)

Both `1` and `2` are of type `int` and have same value category (prvalue). So the type of `m.internalMap[1]` and `m.internalMap[2]` must be the same.

You can only have differing types as outcome if you use different types as input, for example you can use user-defined literals to get a syntax like

```
m.internalMap[1_c]
```

or if you use the index as a template argument instead of a function argument / expression operand:

```
m.internalMap.someFunction<1>();
```

In either case this works only if the index is a compile-time constant and it isn't really useful, because you would need to know at compile-time which type is stored at which index, in which case using `std::variant` in the first place would be unnecessary.

To access elements of the `std::variant` in the map use `std::get` or `std::visit` with a generic lambda that can choose an action based on the type. If there is a type you don't expect at the index you are looking at you'll have to throw an exception or handle the situation in some other way. (`std::get` will throw for you if you use the wrong type.)

```
A a = std::get<A>(m.internalMap[1]);
B b = std::get<B>(m.internalMap[2]);
```

This will throw `std::bad_variant_access` if there isn't a `A` at index `1` and a `B` at index `2`.

Also, just because `internalMap[1]` and `internalMap[2]` have the same type doesn't mean that the syntax

```
A a = m.internalMap[1];
B b = m.internalMap[2];
```

can't work. For example `A` and `B` could have converting constructors from `std::variant<A, B>` or `std::variant<A,B>` could be replaced by a wrapper type around the variant with conversion operators to `A` and `B` (see other answer). In either case, the type mismatch situation would still need to be handled at runtime.

Comment: It's not *quite* impossible. The values in the map could be a type that wraps the variant, which also overloads `operator A&()` and `operator B&()`, and then this would work fine.

Comment: @MooingDuck I am referring to the comment `I want the type of internalMap[1] to be A, and type of internalMap[2] to be B` in OP's code.